# In app purchase is not working under android 2.3.6

Tags: android

In my app I have integrated in app billing system and its working properly in the devices of 2.3.6 and above, but when I test it on 2.3.3 and 2.2.1 then in app billing is not triggered. I have used the following code to test in a button click listener:

```
val = billingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", payloadContents);
```

Is there any documentation that in which version should it run or any solution of it?

Comment: There are responses on the same topic below. Hope these help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457580/android-inapp-billing-billingservice-has-compile-errors-with-onserviceconnecte/11518351#11518351
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651557/android-billing-should-i-implement-the-serviceconnection-or-the-imarketbilling
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099702/android-inappbilling-what-to-do-when-user-presses-the-buy-button/11201382#11201382

Comment: First get the hello world working, and then debug it. Trust me its way easier that way.