# How to implement subscription in "in-app billing" in android subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I had successfully implemented InApp billing with managed products. Now i want to replace that with subscription (IAB V2). I had done all changes that required for subscription as mention in below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

As I purchase items, I get a `request purchse error`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651557/android-billing-should-i-implement-the-serviceconnection-or-the-imarketbilling/11652192#11652192

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457580/android-inapp-billing-billingservice-has-compile-errors-with-onserviceconnecte/11518351#11518351

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099702/android-inappbilling-what-to-do-when-user-presses-the-buy-button/11201382#11201382

Comment: Please post code and/or logcat.

Comment: hi hpique..:)
thanks for reply
i have done all changes correctly and its working now.
but dont know what changes should be done in Security.java and PurchaseDatabase.jave for PurchaseToken

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question. Also, it'd be nice if you posted what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the error with test items?

If yes, then you haven't done all the changes by the letter. Please post code and/or logcat so we can help.

If test items work AND you're getting the error with live items AND you're sure you have implemented all the changes by the letter, then you just might need to wait a few minutes/hours before the new subscription items work.